# How to run an async function in js with timeouts (for rate limiting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, dom, axios

I'm designing a system where a user will interact with my RESTful API through JS, and will replace the `ts` html element with a different SVG if the returned answer is `true`. If the API call returns `false`, the JS should wait for 5 seconds, before retrying the API call. again, if the API call returns `true`, the SVG will be changed, and the function will stop calling the API. How can I have the function "sleep" for 5 seconds before running again, and ending the function if the returned API call is `true`?

Code:

```
async function getTransaction(){
var lookup = $("meta[name='lookup']").attr("content");  
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/client_api/transaction_status/' + lookup) 
.then(function (response) {
    var tStat = response.data.transactionStatus;
    console
    if(tStat){
      document.getElementById("ts").innerHTML = 'drawing the new svg and replacing the old one'
      console.log('transaction_found')
    }
    else if(!tStat){
      console.log("transaction not found")
    }
    else{
      console.log("error")
    }
  });
  }console.log("hello"); while(true){setTimeout(getTransaction,5000);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sleep sice it pauses your programm to pause. Instead use setTimeout like so. This creates an event listener which calls the function again after 5s if `tStat` is `false`.

In case of `false` the function will set an timeout after which the function is called again. After the timeout is completed it clears itself. This step repeats until the api request eventually resolves to `true`

```js
async function getTransaction() {
  var lookup = $("meta[name='lookup']").attr("content");

  axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/client_api/transaction_status/' + lookup)
    .then(function(response) {
      var tStat = response.data.transactionStatus;
      console
      if (tStat) {
        document.getElementById("ts").innerHTML = 'drawing the new svg and replacing the old one'
        console.log('transaction_found')
      } else {
        console.log("transaction not found")
        setTimeout(getTransaction, 5000);
      }
    });
}
console.log("hello");
```